# How can I query a Corda vault for States that contain a Date attribute within a certain date range?

Tags: corda

I have Corda states that are using the java.util.Date attribute. I'd like to be able to perform a vault query to retrieve the States whos Date attribute is within a certain Date range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform an SQL query using `serviceHub.jdbcSession()`. Posted below is an example of a flow that uses this and returns a list of Dates within a given range. `DATE_STATE` is a database table that is created by the `MappedSchema` that is defined specifically for the State I am trying to query for. Information on created a `MappedSchema` for a State can be found here: https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html

```
@StartableByRPC
class QueryDateRangeFlow(val date1: Date, val date2: Date) : FlowLogic<List<Date>>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): List<Date> {
        val connection = serviceHub.jdbcSession()
        val queryString = "SELECT \"DATE\" FROM PUBLIC.DATE_STATE WHERE DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?;"

        val prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString)
        prepStatement.setObject(1, date1)
        prepStatement.setObject(2, date2)

        val rs = prepStatement.executeQuery()
        val list = mutableListOf<Date>()
        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(rs.getObject("DATE", java.util.Date::class.java))
        }
        return list.toList()
    }
}
```